# populate time interval with 30 mintutes between 2 dates

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 time strings for example OPEN = 11:00 and closed is 02:45

now the 02:00 is the next day so i to the following:

```
    //open = string 11:00
    //closed= string 02:45
    $open = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $open);
    $closed = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $closed);
    if ($open > $closed) $closed->modify('+1 day');
```

now i have 2 proper datetime formats. Now i want to set a time interval of 30 minutes from the open time to the close time. How can i do this? i have read i can add like this

```
->add(new DateInterval('PT30M') b
```

ut it will add till the end of the day.. but in this case its open till the next day, so i want it to populate till 2:45AM

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where on the right track. Here is how to do it using `DateInterval('PT30M')`.

```
$strOpen = '11:00';
$strClose = '02:45';

$open = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $strOpen);
$closed = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $strClose);
if ($open > $closed) $closed->modify('+1 day');
// I display not only the time, but the day as well to show that it is
// incrementing to the next day. 
echo 'open:  ' . $open->format('D H:i') . "<br />\n";
while ($open < $closed) {
    $open->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
    // because incrementing on the half hour and our finish is on the 15 min,
    // the last is $open < $close in the while statement will be true but
    // this loop will generate a time after $closed so we do another check
    // now to eliminate that issue
    if ($open < $closed) {
        echo '+30min: ' . $open->format('D H:i') . "<br />\n";
    }
}
echo 'closed: ' . $closed->format('D H:i') . "<br />\n";
```